# Installing Windows 7 on a Macbook and resizing later

Tags: windows-7, macbook, partitioning

I wish to install Windows 7 on my Macbook White 13in. I plan to use boot camp to create a partition for the windows and work through the install wizard.

If I decide that it works well and I want to increase the available disk space for Windows 7, can I resize it at a later date? and if so what would I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iPartition](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php) isn't free, but it's worked for me with both XP and Vista. I can't see why it wouldn't work well with Windows 7 too.

Comment: thanks, i actually ended up doing a total format of my mac and installing win 7 from scratch. Combined with the bootcamp 3.0 drivers it runs like a dream. I'm now rocking out on an over-priced windows 7 machine, but it works for me since I've made the shift from Graphic design to SEO, and need a lot of windows tools :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the GParted LiveCD to boot up and resize your partitions

[Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)